# How to take screenshot of the videoView current frame?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am trying to take the screenshot of current frame of videoplaying in the videoview. I didn't find any helpful programs. Can anyone show me the whole procedure please.

```
ublic Bitmap getBitmapVideoView(){
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(getVideoURL());
            int currentPosition =videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context.getApplicationContext(),uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(-1L);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Errorrr",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
```

The above code isn't working it showing invalid uri exception even though this video is being played perfectly in the video view.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack overflow. So what you have try ? please put some code.

Comment: Thank you .Have a look.